# What is the OpenSSL 3.0 replacement for creating an EVP_PKEY from RSA key PEMs using PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey() + EVP_PKEY_assign()?

Tags: openssl, cryptography

I'm porting legacy OpenSSL v1.1.1 client code that generates EVP_PKEYs from existing RSA keys in PEM format. The resulting EVP_PKEYs are used in various crypto operations.

The legacy method for creating a EVP_PKEY from a PEM-based RSA key is using a combination of PEM_read_bio_RSA[Private|Public]Key(...) and EVP_PKEY_assignRSA(...). However these functions have been deprecated since OpenSSL 3.0 according to the following compiler errors:

error C4996: 'PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey': Since OpenSSL 3.0

error C4996: 'EVP_PKEY_assign': Since OpenSSL 3.0

What is the 3.0+ way of accomplishing same?

Comment: That's not just legacy, it's badly written; `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` was the _preferred_ method to get EVP_PKEY from _all_ PEM privatekey formats way back to 0.9.x! Anyway, the 3.0+ way of reading _all kinds_ of PEM files is [the 'STORE' interface](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man7/ossl_store.html).

Comment: Thanks Dave. As usual, the docs are sparse and tedious to navigate from a scenario (vs API) perspective. In addition to creating an EVP_PKEY from isolated key PEMs, another use case is extracting the public key as EVP_PKEY from an x509. I’ll be able to figure it out, but if you’ve already got mileage on the STORE interface, a sample would benefit myself and others. Otherwise I’ll post one when I get back to it (the workaround I posted below suffices in the interim). Thanks!

Comment: I've looked at STORE a bit but not used it yet. From the `X509` object for a certificate (which also can be read through a STORE, or for which PEM_read is NOT deprecated) see `X509_get[0]_pubkey`.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL docs are a joy :) The sequence needed:

```
char *name, *header;
unsigned char* data;
long datalen;

if (0 == PEM_read_bio(
     keybio, // loaded with key PEM contents using BIO_new_mem_buf()
     &name, &header, &data, &datalen))
{
    const unsigned char* data_pkey = (const unsigned char*)data;
    EVP_PKEY* pkey = d2i_AutoPrivateKey(NULL, &data_pkey), datalen);

    // ... validate and use pkey as needed ...

    OPENSSL_free(name);
    OPENSSL_free(header);
    OPENSSL_free(data);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to some typos (such as the parenthesis just after `&data_pkey`), there's a conceptual mistake in shonji's response regarding the return value of `PEM_read_bio`. As the documentation for OpenSSL 3.2 states (see "Return Values" section of [PEM_read_bio](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man3/PEM_read_bio.html)):

> PEM_read() and PEM_read_bio() return 1 on success and 0 on failure

This is how it should be used:

```
uint8_t dataPEM[] = "-----BEGIN...KEY-----";

// Creates a BIO reader. Data source will not be duplicated
BIO *bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(dataPEM, -1);
if (bio == NULL) /* ERROR */ ;

// Reads PEM information and retrieves some details
char *name = NULL, *header = NULL;
uint8_t *data = NULL;
long datalen = 0;
if (PEM_read_bio(bio, &name, &header, &data, &datalen) == 1)
{
    // Copies the data pointer. D2I functions update it
    const uint8_t *data_pkey = (const uint8_t*)data;
    // Detects type and decodes the private key
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = d2i_AutoPrivateKey(NULL, &data_pkey, datalen);

    // ... validate and use pkey as needed ...

    // Free is only required after a PEM_bio_read successful return
    if (name != NULL)  OPENSSL_free(name);
    if (header != NULL) OPENSSL_free(header);
    if (data != NULL) OPENSSL_free(data);
}
else /* ERROR */ ;

if (bio != NULL) BIO_free(bio);
```

References: See [BIO_new_mem_buf](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man3/BIO_new_mem_buf.html) and [d2i_AutoPrivateKey](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.2/man3/d2i_AutoPrivateKey.html).

I did not have enough reputation to comment on shonji's response.